# How to get position ofeditor relative to the whole screen

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an Eclipse Editor Plugin
Now, I want to pop up a window at the right bottom corner of selected content. This window is written by JFrame and I need to use setLocation.
I can get the position of selected content relative to the editor, but how can I get the position of upper left corner of editor relative to the whole screen?

Comment: Note: using Swing components such as JFrame in an Eclipse plug-in which uses SWT is difficult to get right and should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `toDisplay` method of the main SWT `Composite` for the editor part to convert a point in the composite to a display relative point:

```
public Point toDisplay(int x, int y)
```

or

```
public Point toDisplay(Point point)
```

You can use `toDisplay` for any `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

this function comes from org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist
I use it to get the coordinates

Point location = control.getDisplay().map(control.getParent(), null, control.getLocation());

Comment: `Display.map` does exactly the same thing as `Control.toDisplay` but needs more parameters.